# Who placed first on entrance exam 1805 at École Polytechnique?

Tags: france, science, mathematics

[Wikipedia:Cauchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augustin-Louis_Cauchy) and [Biography of Cauchy](https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Cauchy/) say that in 1805 Augustin Cauchy placed second of 293 applicants on the entrance exam at [École Polytechnique](https://www.polytechnique.edu/en).  Who placed first?

Comment: Hi and welcome to History SE. Please let us know where you have already looked so that others don't duplicate your efforts. Thank you.

Comment: Hi. Lars is aking you to [edit](https://history.stackexchange.com/posts/69991/edit) your question to list the "multiple sources" that you refer to

Comment: Since Polytechnique is a state-run school, I would expect the exam results to be published in the official record of government acts — at the time the *Moniteur universel*. I tried [searching the Moniteur for 1805](https://gallica.bnf.fr/services/engine/search/sru?operation=searchRetrieve&version=1.2&startRecord=0&maximumRecords=15&page=1&collapsing=disabled&query=arkPress%20all%20%22cb34452336z_date%22%20and%20dc.date%3D%221805%22%20and%20%28gallica%20all%20%22polytechnique%22%29), and found various things including entrance requirements and the exam date but not the results.

Answer (score 8):

Article "*The "Ecole Polytechnique", 1794-1850: Differences over Educational Purpose and Teaching Practice*" in **The American Mathematical Monthly** Vol. 112, No. 3 (Mar 2005), [available on JSTOR](https://www.jstor.org/stable/30037440?origin=crossref#metadata_info_tab_contents), lists in **Table 2** "*by years of enrolment the students who later led distinguished careers in and around mathematics at the school and/or elsewhere.*"

For the year 1805, the only name given in **Table 2** is Cauchy.

Whoever it was that scored better than Cauchy on the 1805 entrance, they didn't become notable in Mathematics.

Comment: The only other possible source would be records of the École itself, and they may not have survived.

Comment: @Spencer Uh? Since the Ecole is publicly run, I would expect the primary source to be a government publication, though I couldn't locate the information. And why would this one article in the AMM be the only possible secondary source?

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' You can always email them directly.

Comment: I have only been able to find a list of the names of the 125 students admitted to the École in 1805. I also came across one archival list (that I did *not* bookmark) that seemed to indicate that the grades (*notes*) from the early years of the school are no longer extant. The fact that Cauchy placed second in the entrance exam is mentioned in an early biography: C. A. Valson, *La Vie et les Travaux du Baron Cauchy*, Paris 1868, [p. 22](https://www.google.com/books/edition/La_vie_et_les_travaux_du_baron_Cauchy/vQ7tw0rVKPsC?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=RA1-PA22&printsec=frontcover).